# Remote access via web, to USB device

Tags: usb

Some of my customers are in presence of a USB device , which I from time to time need to do configuration work on.

The thing is, that i order to reconfigure these devices, a rather heavy (and costly) application is needed. In other words, this is an application I got, and they don't.

When I got the option of physically going there, this is straight forward.

But obviously I would like to do remote support. I know that there are several "remote USB" applications out there, but until now, it seems (which makes very good sense) that this requires port forwarding configuration to be done on all of my customers routers/firewalls, and requires them to have fixed public IP's.

Are there any "gateway" solutions out there, similar to how Teamviewer, etc works, which will allow my application to connect to a USB device across WAN?

Or would it be possible to develop a such?

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a dynamic DNS for your PC. Then you can use netcat reverse shell to connect from the customers PC to yours. To make it simple you could write a simple script or application for you customers, that shouldn't be complicated.

```
Your machine:
ncat -v -l -p 1234

Customers machine: (3333 is the port of the tcp <-> usb software)
nc your-dns 1234 -e “nc localhost 3333″
```

Make sure you forward the port 1234 on your router.

Comment: Interesting thought. But I would expect that port 3333 would be blocked in (WAN wise) on most setups?

Comment: I know that port 3333 was just an example. But the challange would remain the same no matter what port you would use

Comment: Whats about port 80 ? Or is HTTP blocked ?